# Python Opencv2 + webcam facial dection, no face being detected no error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I'm using a guide provided online with opencv2.4 that shows you how to detect faces with opencv2 and python. I followed the guide and understand what it says. However I can't seem to find the issue with my program because the video shows but now face is detected and the video is very clear. There are no errors. I ran in debug mode and the value faces remains a blank tuple so I'm assuming that means its not finding the face. What I don't understand is why and I think it has something to do with the hash table.

By hash table I mean the cascade xml file. I understand cascades are basically the guidelines for detecting the facial artifacts correct?

Links to the guides. The hash table i.e the xml file is on the github linked.

https://github.com/shantnu/FaceDetect/blob/master/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam/

```
import cv2
import sys
import os
#cascPath = sys.argv[1]
cascPath = os.getcwd()+'facehash.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
print faceCascade
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            )
    cv2.cv
    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong path to your xml classifier. (I guess you've changed the name to get a shorter form).

**Instead of your cascPath:**

```
cascPath = os.getcwd()+'facehash.xml'
```

**Try this:**

```
cascPath = "{base_path}/folder_with_your_xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml".format(
    base_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

And now it should work as well.